# How do I deploy the personal ordnance drop?

Tags: halo-4

I've had the ordinance drop icon in Halo 4 infinity multiplayer on my screen (upper middle center). My question is what button do I press to select/deploy the ordinance drop? I can't find any help on this.

Answer (score 3):

The ordnance drop is triggered by pressing a direction on your D-Pad.  Which direction you push depends on which of the 3 ordnance choices you'd like.  Left, down, and right represent different ordinances, as indicated by the icons in the top center of your HUD.

Answer (score 0):

As agent 86 says, the left/down/right arrows on the D-Pad will select your drop. Bear in mind that not every drop is a power weapon, and will contain a selection of power weapons, grenades, overshield/speed boost and other weapons such as the needler.

The drop will land around where your gun recitle is pointing, so don't use it when zoomed in through a sniper rifle unless you want to donate your ordnance to the enemy. If you are out in the open the caniseter will be dropped by the Infinity (yes, it's possible to splatter enemies and destory vehicles with it) or if you're in cover such as caves, it will be teleported in.

There's also no need to call in the drop as soon as you get it - ordnance drops "roll over" after you die so if you see you have a sniper or binary rifle waiting for you, it might be an idea to wait until you die and then choose a loadout with Active Camo and the unlock that shows the motion tracker while zoomed in.

Answer (score 0):

what agent86 and tombull89 say are true. but they're missing something. there is a tactical package you can unlock called "Requisition." it allows you to request your choice of ordnance drops. its useful in PVP but i dont know if it helps in spartan ops.

Answer (score -1):

If the ordanance doesn't give you options you like, don't just use it to use it. Wait until your out of amo or in some cases don't have another gun